# JQuery Change and Load functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

The below query works great when it comes to checking radio buttons and having the "result value" display.

How do I have the "result value" display on page load since the radio buttons already have checked inputs?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('input[name*="fed"], input[name*="stake"]').change(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
        $wrap = $this.closest('.js-weight-calc-wrap'),
        fedVal = $wrap.find('input[name*="fed"]:checked').val(),
        stakeVal = $wrap.find('input[name*="stake"]:checked').val(),
        result = fedVal === 'Very High' ? '3'
             : fedVal === 'High' && stakeVal === 'Very High' ? '3'
             : fedVal === 'Low to Moderate' && stakeVal !== 'Very High' ? '1'
             : '2';
        $wrap.find('.js-result').text(result)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to just trigger the change event on the input manually on dom ready.

```
$('input[name*="fed"], input[name*="stake"]').trigger('change');
```

Comment: No, just add my line after your change function.